# Failed commit in SmartGit

Tags: git, git-commit, smartgit

I did a commit (& push) in SmartGit but I was not connected to the internet. It is represented by a red cross in SmartGits "Output"-window. The text reads: Unable to access '**_____**': could not resolve host: '**_____**'. After this I did a successful commit of some other files and a successful push.

Do I need to fix something? Will the failed commit that happened earlier mess things up or is everything ok?

Comment: No, assuming both commits were on the same branch, the successful push would have sent both commits to the remote server and all is well.  If commits were on different branches, you may need to push the branch that failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine. You should see now two commits in the **Outgoing** view. Once you are connected to the Internet, just invoke **Push** and your commits will be transmitted to the server.